# How to select the checkbox as per the html using Selenium WebDriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have a checkbox which I need to select using Selenium. Below is the `HTML`:

```
<input id="diDataCheck" ng-model="$parent.DIDATA.IsSet" name="Mode" type="checkbox" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" xpath="1">
```

I have tried accessing it using its `id` or `name` and even with `XPath` but it doesn't seems to be working.

```
CHECKBOX = (By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(text(), 'diDataCheck')]""") # using XPATH
CHECKBOX = (By.ID, "diDataCheck") # using id
CHECKBOX = (By.NAME, "Mode") # using name
```

I am using above as:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(CHECKBOX)).click()
```

I also put the above line in `try except` but I got nothing in `Exception message`.

When I changed the `WebDriverWait()` to:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("diDataCheck").click()
```

I got exception as:

`Message: element not visible`

Comment: Is the CheckBox visible on the HTML page?

Comment: XPath is incorrect as `input` cannot contain text. Share how you implemented `try`/`except` and explain what does *got nothing in Exception message* means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath with wait condition

```
checkElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Mode' and  @type='checkbox']")));

checkElement.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('diDataCheck').click()")
```

But there's no 'safe' way of knowing if the button was pressed, so take that in mind. You can implement a change eventHandler on the input element if you want to know for sure if the checkbox was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shered the *checkbox* is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to invoke `click()` on it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty#diDataCheck[name='Mode']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty' and @id='diDataCheck'][@name='Mode']"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It isn't working with `CSS_SELECTOR` and `XPATH` you mentioned. I don't know whats wrong here.

Comment: Checkout my updated answer. What does the error says? Update the question with the error trace logs for analysis.